# Why I have error with operator ampersand &&?

Tags: ruby

Im interesting with syntax error in Ruby, when I use brackets with `include?` and `&&`, nothing bad, but if I wont use brackets, I have syntax error. Here is my code example:

```
names = ["Sony", "Mac"]
if names.include? "Sony" && names.include? "Mac"
  puts names
end # will be error


names = ["Sony", "Mac"]
if names.include?("Sony") && names.include?("Mac")
    puts names
end # good


names = ["Sony", "Mac"]
if names.include? "Sony" and names.include? "Mac"
  puts names
end # good
```

Could u pls explain to me, why so?

Comment: Order of operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every programming language needs to parse ambiguous statements into a specific evaluation order. In most languages (including Ruby) `&&` has a very high precedence in order to match the common convention from mathematics where `&&` and `||` are analogous to `*` and `+`, respectively. The same way that `A + B * C` is evaluated as `A + (B * C)`, `A || B && C` is evaluated as `A || (B && C)`.

So your first example is parsed the same as

```
if names.include?("Sony" && names.include?) "Mac"
```

There are several errors in this line, but the syntax error is hit first because this expression has the form

```
if x.y(z) "Mac"
```

which is not a valid Ruby expression.

`and` on the other hand is not for Boolean logic but for sequencing operations like "do this *and* do that". The intent is that you can take any two expressions in Ruby and put an `and` between them to make the second expression conditional on the first one. In order for this to work, `and` needs very *low* precedence in order to not change how the two expressions are parsed.

It is usually recommended to avoid using `and` and `or` inside `if` statements to avoid confusion.

Comment: I don't think you're grappling with the heart of the issue, which is Ruby's ability to let you omit the parentheses when giving a single method parameter. I've never liked this, and here it has misled the OP completely.

Comment: @matt you can omit parentheses for any number of parameters. Personally I've never found it any more confusing than the kind of expressions allowed in any language e.g. `A + B * C - D / E * F + G`. The rule is the same: use parentheses to make your code more understandable, omit them if it's clear without! If you know that rule, it still doesn't explain exactly how and why `&&` and `and` work, which is what my answer covers.

Comment: "Every programming language needs to parse ambiguous statements into a specific evaluation order." – This has nothing to do with evaluation order. Since there is a syntax error, the code isn't even being evaluated *at all*, so it cannot possibly be related to evaluation order. The issue is *precedence*, not evaluation order.

Comment: @JörgWMittag doesn't the precedence used by the parser determine the order in which the expression will be evaluated? I originally said just "precedence" in my answer but that begs the question "Precedence of _what_?" Precedence on its own does not describe what is happening.